# Setting cursor position for a UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Does anyone have a good Swift solution for setting the cursor position in a UITextField? Here's how my fields look now.  I would like to add a bit of spacing before the start point of the cursor.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `leftView` property of `UITexField` to achieve this.

Here's an example:

```
let passwordField = UITextField()
...
// this will add a 8pt padding to the textField
passwordField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 0));
passwordField.leftViewMode = .Always
```